Fetching Blog Content Data in my Edit Blog Modal Using Ajax
This is my HTML for Blog Content which is using ckeditor.
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
       <div class="form-group mb-0">
          <label class="form-label" for="edit-blog-editor">Blog Content: <span class="validation">*</span></label>
          <textarea id="edit-blog-editor" name="edit-blog-editor"></textarea>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

Ckeditor is initialised and is working for both add blog modal and edit blog modal.
But While fetching the data using ajax. i am facing an issue. Issue is that i am able to get my content as a response and in console.log as well.
Below is the code for fetching blog data using ajax
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return textArea.value;
  }

  function fetchBlogContent(blogId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax-blog/fetch_blog_content.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { eid: blogId },
      dataType: "text",
      success: function (content) {
        console.log("Received content:", content);
        CKEDITOR.instances["edit-blog-editor"].destroy();
        $("#edit-blog-editor").val(decodeEntities(content));
        CKEDITOR.replace("edit-blog-editor");
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching blog content:", error);
      },
    });
  }

console.log("Received content:", content); this code is returning the blog content data in console.
But After that i am not able to see the data in the text editor.
This is how i am fetching rest of the data
$("#blog-table").on("click", "#edit-blog-button", function () {
    let blogId = $(this).data("eid");
    $.ajax({
      url: "ajax-blog/fetch_blog.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: { blogId: blogId },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        // Populate modal fields
        $("#edit_blog_id").val(blogId);
        $("#edit-blog-title").val(data.title);
        $("#edit-blog-short-desc").val(data.short_description);
        $("#edit-blog-img-alt").val(data.image_alt);
        $("#edit-blog-posted-by").val(data.posted_by);
        $("#edit-blog-posted-on").val(data.posted_on);
        $("#edit-blog-meta-title").val(data.meta_title);
        $("#edit-blog-meta-desc").val(data.meta_description);
        $("#edit-blog-meta-key").val(data.meta_keywords);
        $("#edit-blog-category").val(data.category_slug);
        $("#edit-popular-blog").prop("checked", data.popular_blog === "yes");
        $("#edit-trending-blog").prop("checked", data.trending_blog === "yes");
        $("#edit-top-blog").prop("checked", data.top_blog === "yes");
        $("#edit-blog-slug-url").val(data.slug_url);

        fetchBlogContent(blogId);

        fetchCurrentImage(blogId);
      },
      error: function (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching blog details:", error);
      },
    });
  });

This is how i am fetching blog content using php
<?php

include("../include/config.php");

if (isset($_POST['eid'])) {
    $blogId = $_POST['eid'];

    $fetch_query = "SELECT blog_content FROM blogs WHERE id=?";
    $fetch_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $fetch_query);

    if ($fetch_stmt) {
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($fetch_stmt, "i", $blogId);
        if (mysqli_stmt_execute($fetch_stmt)) {
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($fetch_stmt);
            $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

            echo json_encode($row);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(["error" => "Execution failed"]);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(["error" => "Prepare failed"]);
    }

    mysqli_stmt_close($fetch_stmt);
    mysqli_close($conn);
}

I just want to show the data in ckeditor and i have no idea anymore how to resolve this.
i tried to initialise CK editor again. checked all the response up until putting data in the actual textarea. Which is not working at all.
I just want to fetch my data according to that id in ckeditor.

If content has the content than PHP is not the issue. You should make the issue as focused as possible. Are there errors in console? Not too familiar with ckeditor but destroy() doesnt sound like something I'd use. I would think just injected the html into the container ckeditor is running on would update it... That's a guess though, PHP brought me here and this is not related to that.
